# In Gulp how do you only SFTP files which have changed after minification?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp

Using `gulp-sftp`, I can't seem to only upload the file that has changed after CSS minification.

The semi-working snippet below begins by compiling the CSS and then continues to watch for changes in the `src` dir. It follows on by watching for changes in the `dist` dir (where minified CSS is stored) in order to upload that file to a web server.

However, this does not work as `gulp` is uploading everything rather than only the file that has changed and been minified.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    sftp = require('gulp-sftp')
;

var src = './src/',
    dist = './dist/';

var srcStyles = src + '**/*.css',
    distStyles = dist + '**/*.css';

var host = 'ftp.xxxx.xx.xx',
    auth = 'keyMain',
    remotePath = 'public_html';

gulp.task('compilecss', function(){
    gulp.src(srcStyles)
        .pipe(changed(dist))
        .pipe(minifycss({keepBreaks: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
    ;
});

gulp.task('uploadcss', function(){
    gulp.src(distStyles)
        .pipe(changed(dist))
        .pipe(sftp({
            host: host,
            auth: auth,
            remotePath: remotePath
        }))
    ;
});

gulp.task('main', function(){
    gulp.start('compilecss');
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(srcStyles, ['compilecss']);
    gulp.watch(distStyles, ['uploadcss']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['main', 'watch']);
```

Comment: You asked the same question over here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/465, maybe you care in sharing the results here?

Comment: Apologies - I've now answered my own question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for two tasks. gulp is file-based which means you should think in pipelines, not tasks.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  changed = require('gulp-changed'),
  minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
  sftp = require('gulp-sftp');

var src = './src/',
  dist = './dist/';

var srcStyles = src + '**/*.css',
  distStyles = dist + '**/*.css';

var host = 'ftp.xxxx.xx.xx',
  auth = 'keyMain',
  remotePath = 'public_html';

gulp.task('compile', function (){
  return gulp.src(srcStyles)
    .pipe(changed(dist))
    .pipe(minifycss({
      keepBreaks: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
    .pipe(sftp({
      host: host,
      auth: auth,
      remotePath: remotePath
    }));
});

gulp.task('watch', function (){
  gulp.watch(srcStyles, ['compile']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['compile', 'watch']);
```

Comment: `gulp-sftp` closed the connection right after the upload, making it very slow next time a file is changed... Is there a way to go around this and keep the connection open for future uploads?